# Rancher and jenkins configuration?

Tags: jenkins, rancher

Problem context

1. I have worked on jenkins where in installed jenkins war on linux machine and created jobs to interact with Git and deploy code
2. Racnher cluster is configured with three nodes rancher,master,worker

Where to start ?

1. Now to setup jenkins do i need to install jenkins war separatly (java -jar jenkins.war) on same/any other VM and use the jenkins jobs to deploy containers on rancher cluster ??
2. Is there any easiest way ?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got solution.My company has embeded jenkins/git configuration and from jenkins pipeline i am deploying app to kr cluster using intermediate binary storages,company owned dockerhub

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really the easiest way for this, you gonna have to brute force it